# How to read nested json in d3.js pie chart?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, pie-chart

I want to create pie chart from the nested json file. Here is the simple json which I am using right now.

Sample Json file

```
    [
    {
    "origin":"June2013",
    "carrier":"9E",
    "count":5
    },
    {
    "origin":"June2013",
    "carrier":"AA",
    "count":22
   },

    {
    " origin":"June2013",
    "carrier":"MQ",
    "count":2

    },

   {
  "origin":"July 2013",
  "carrier":"9E",
  "count":2
  },
  {
  "origin":"July 2013",
  "carrier":"AA",
  "count":448
  },

 {
 "origin":"July 2013",
 "carrier":"XE",
 "count":4
 }]
```

Nested json that I created from this ( I suppose to use this one)

```
{

"title":[{"caption":"Alert"}],
"xaxis":[{"name":"origin","label":"Month Year"}],
"yaxis":[{"name":"count","label":"Alert Number"}],
"table":[{
"column1":"origin",
"column2":"count",
"column3":"carrier"}],
"data":[
{
"origin":"June2013",
"carrier":"9E",
"count":5
},
{
"origin":"June2013",
"carrier":"AA",
"count":22
},
{
"origin":"June2013",
"carrier":"MQ",
"count":2
}]
 }
```

My sample javascript file

```
<script type="text/javascript">


d3.json("flights.json", function(flights) {

var m = 10,
  r = 100,
  z = d3.scale.category20c();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d) { return +d.count; })
  .sort(function(a, b) { return b.count - a.count; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(r / 2)
  .outerRadius(r);

var airports = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.origin; })
  .entries(flights);

var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
  .data(airports)
  .enter().append("div") 
  .style("display", "inline-block")
  .style("width", (r + m) * 2 + "px")
  .style("height", (r + m) * 2 + "px")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", (r + m) * 2)
  .attr("height", (r + m) * 2)
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + m) + "," + (r + m) + ")");

 svg.append("svg:text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

 var g = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(function(d) { return pie(d.values); })
  .enter().append("svg:g");

 g.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return z(d.data.carrier); })
  .append("svg:title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.carrier + ": " + d.data.count; });

 g.filter(function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; }).append("svg:text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d)        + ")"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.carrier; });

  function angle(d) {
  var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
  return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
  }
  });

  </script>
```

Expected output looks like this

```
 http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305337
```

I am new to this, not aware much how to read nested json over here, it would be good if anyone can give me pointer in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entries to your d3.nest needs to be the flights.data property (the array of objects)

```
.entries(flights.data);
```

**Elaboration:**

See [d3.nest Documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest). 
To summarize, in your case, the d3.nest() operator

- Takes a flat collection (an array of objects) specified by `nest.entries(flights.data)`
- returns a hierarchichal (in your case there is only one level June2013) grouping grouped by the key accessor function you specify using `next.key(function(d) { return d.origin; })`

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zLxzf1fw/, check out this section below and inspect the logs in developer tools

```
// before
console.log(flights.data);
var airports = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.origin; })
  .entries(flights.data);
// after
console.log(airports);
```

To summarize, you were previously not given a structure for which your .key accessor wasn't returning entries. Hope this helps out a tad more.